# Store cart and delete items in static website

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Vanilla javascript to manipulate items in Cart .
Whenever i want to delete an item i want to store it when I refresh the page , I didn't succeed using localStorage in this case :

```
function Cart()
{
for(let i = 0 ; i <addCart.length; i++ )
{
    addCart[i].addEventListener('click', (event)=>
    {
       const Target = event.target
       const titleTarget = Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].innerText
       const priceTarget = Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText
       const imageTarget = Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src
        addToCart(titleTarget,priceTarget,imageTarget)
       console.log(titleTarget,priceTarget,imageTarget)
       addCart[i].parentElement.remove()

    })
}
    function addToCart(titleTarget,priceTarget,imageTarget)
    {
        var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
        cartRow.classList.add('grid-cart')
        var cartRowContent = `
                <img class="cart-image" src="${imageTarget}" alt="cart image" />
            <div class="grid-title">
                <h3 class="cart-title">${titleTarget}</h3>
                <h4 class="cart-title-size">Size 11</h4>
            </div>
                <h3 class="cart-price">${priceTarget}</h3>
        `
        cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContent
        dropCart[0].append(cartRow)
    }
   
}
localStorage.setItem('cartsetting',Cart())
localStorage.getItem('cartsetting')
```

So this code describes , that I will click add to cart and it will be removed from the main page . And will be added in the cart , but everything get reset after I refresh ! any solution ?

Comment: I don't think your code sample is complete, as `addCart` is undefined. That said, on refresh you first _set_ an item in Local Storage and then read it, so the read value will always be new in that case. You should be doing something more like reading whether there is a cart first before overwriting it.

Comment: Pls check whether you are even able to store it in local storage when the page hasn’t refreshed. Also pls post your code with all the missing variables’ definition

Answer (score 0):

you should check if your localstorage still has the value 'cartsetting' defined or not. Check following code:

```
  function Cart() {
   for (let i = 0; i < addCart.length; i++) {
    addCart[i].addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const Target = event.target;
    const titleTarget =
      Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0]
        .innerText;
    const priceTarget =
      Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]
        .innerText;
    const imageTarget =
      Target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src;
    addToCart(titleTarget, priceTarget, imageTarget);
    console.log(titleTarget, priceTarget, imageTarget);
    addCart[i].parentElement.remove();
   });
  }
  function addToCart(titleTarget, priceTarget, imageTarget) {
   var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
   cartRow.classList.add("grid-cart");
   var cartRowContent = `
              <img class="cart-image" src="${imageTarget}" alt="cart image" />
          <div class="grid-title">
              <h3 class="cart-title">${titleTarget}</h3>
             <h4 class="cart-title-size">Size 11</h4>
         </div>
              <h3 class="cart-price">${priceTarget}</h3>
      `;
      cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContent;
      dropCart[0].append(cartRow);
      }
     }
      if(!localStorage.getItem('cartsetting')) {
         localStorage.setItem("cartsetting", Cart());
       }
     localStorage.getItem("cartsetting");
```

This will prevent localstorage to reset on page refresh